# Multirow does not work in Czech language

Tags: tables, babel, multirow, languages

I inserted Multirow to my table and I have tested with differents languages (Spanish, Italian, Arabic,Chinese,Russian,Portuguese) and it converges with all of them. Also converges when I disable babel (without that, it seems continue with English for default). However, I am working with Czech language, and there it does not converges.
Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow} 


\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
       \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Social}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Waiting time}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Waiting time}} & 1.000 & 8.000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}          & 0.125 & 1.000 \\
    \midrule
    Location & 0.167 & 0.200 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: As oposed to the title of your question, this is not caused by the use of `\multirow` but by the `-` in `\cmidrule{2-3}`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is caused by special signs like hyphen character. It can be temporary shut off with  `\shorthandoff{-}` and  `\shorthandon{-}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow} 


\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \shorthandoff{-}
       \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Social}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Waiting time}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{Waiting time}} & 1.000 & 8.000 \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}          & 0.125 & 1.000 \\
    \midrule
    Location & 0.167 & 0.200 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\shorthandon{-}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Roland, I apreciate it. Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem is not `\mutirow`, but the `\cmidrule` parameter. The same would happen with `\cline`, however. Because `-` is used so much, I guess there will be other cases, where it will fail.

Comment: @Pieter, Thank you. Then, for future, anytime when I see  this character `-`, I will temporary shut off babel with `\shorthandoff{-}` and `\shorthandon{-}` like said @Roland.